# Store loop object in vue.js

Tags: vuejs2, loops

I would like to store loop object in `id` of HTML element so that I can use it when click on this element. My code is like below

```
<tr v-for="obj in data">
    <td v-for="(value, key) in obj" :id="obj"></td>
</tr>
```

But it is not working. Could anyone help me in this regard ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Can Call Method On Click Of `td` element of table , and pass current obj to that method.

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    arr:[{name:'Demo User',email:'demoUser@gmail.com'},             {name:'James Bond',email:'james@gmail.com'}]
      },
  methods:{
    getData:function(item){
       alert(item.name+"--"+item.email);
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
<table border="1">
<tbody>
<tr v-for="item in arr">
    <td v-for="(value, key) in item" v-on:click="getData(item)">{{value}}</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```